# Function to Shrink a List By ONE Haskell

Tags: haskell

Trying to return a list with the last element removed. Why am I getting this error?

```
ERROR file:.\ShrinkByOne.hs:5 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : (lis !! n : result) lis n
*** Term           : (:)
*** Type           : f -> [f] -> [f]
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d -> e

shrinkByOne :: [Int]  -> [Int]  -> Int ->  [Int]
shrinkByOne result lis n
    | n <= ((length lis) - 2) = shrinkByOne ( ((lis !! n):result) lis n+1) -- this condition prevents the last element from being returned
    | otherwise = result
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why the error?

In your original code, you had something like that:

```
shrinkByOne (... something ...)
```

which meant that you applied only one argument to `shrinkByOne`.  You need this instead:

```
shrinkByOne (... something ...) (... something ...) (... something ...)
```

Therefore, put parentheses this way:

```
shrinkByOne :: [Int]  -> [Int]  -> Int ->  [Int]
shrinkByOne result lis n
    | n <= ((length lis) - 2) = shrinkByOne ((lis !! n):result) lis (n+1) -- this condition prevents the last element from being returned
    | otherwise = result
```

### Other remarks

However, you will still not get the desired result, as the result will be reversed and the `!!` is expensive, and your function will be of Θ(n²) complexity.

Try a much simpler, linear approach:

```
shrinkByOne' :: [Int] -> [Int]
shrinkByOne' [x] = []
shrinkByOne' (x : xs) = x : shrinkByOne' xs
```

Finally, I understand that this is an exercise to learn Haskell.  If it's not, simply use the [`init`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:init) function from the Prelude.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the more fundamental problems with the OP's approach.

Answer (score 4):

First, you want to leave out unneeded parens around function arguments. `f(x)` is written `f x` in Haskell (that one's just optional), and in particular you can't write `g (x y)` if `g :: A -> B -> C`, it needs to be `g x y` (or possibly `g (x) (y)`. But `g (x y)` would mean, you apply the function `x` to the argument `y`, and use the result as argument for `g`. (If you actually want that, write `g $ x y`, or `g . x $ y`.)

So that would mean `shrinkByOne ((lis !! n):result) lis n+1`. Which would, however, be parsed as `(shrinkByOne ((lis !! n):result) lis n) + 1`: infix operators like `+` always have *lower precedence* than function application, so indeed around `n+1` you do need parens.